# MongoDB ingestion very slow

Tags: mongodb, nosql

**Problem**

We are attempting to ingest **6 billion elements** into a sharded cluster and ingestion starts very fast but slows down to almost zero progress after a large number of elements are inserted (e.g 5 / 6 billion). We have tried disabling the balancer and not indexing until after ingestion but neither have helped.

**Attributes of the data and ingestion pattern:**

1. Chunk size: 64MB (default)
2. Batch size (i.e. size of bulk requests): 1000
3. 12 threads per node doing concurrent bulk requests of size 1000 documents
4. Average document size: 568.7417637713185
5. Number of chunks: 66586

**Points of interest in the mongo logs include:** Consistent splitVector() & splitChunk() calls with a gradually increasing number of splits per call (e.g. 2 at the beginning and over 3k with 5bn+ elements ingested).

**Excerpt from start of ingestion when throughput is very good - notice the low split count**

```
2016-12-12T18:21:15.652+0000 W SHARDING [conn139] Finding the split vector for db.d1 over { _id: "hashed" } keyCount: 59074 numSplits: 2 lookedAt
: 11332 took 146ms
2016-12-12T18:21:15.652+0000 I COMMAND  [conn139] command admin.$cmd command: splitVector { splitVector: "db.d1", keyPattern: { _id: "hashed" }, 
min: { _id: 8891696537615988474 }, max: { _id: MaxKey }, maxChunkSizeBytes: 67108864, maxSplitPoints: 0, maxChunkObjects: 250000 } keyUpdates:0 w
riteConflicts:0 numYields:1011 reslen:208 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2024 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1012 } }, Collection: { a
cquireCount: { r: 1012 } } } protocol:op_command 146ms
2016-12-12T18:21:15.652+0000 I SHARDING [conn131] received splitChunk request: { splitChunk: "db.d1", keyPattern: { _id: "hashed" }, min: { _id: 
8891696537615988474 }, max: { _id: MaxKey }, from: "shardrepl6", splitKeys: [ { _id: 9043183284609251672 }, { _id: 9194457032126213414 } ], confi
gdb: "configrep/nohdp-m:27019,nohdp-w-0:27019,nohdp-w-1:27019", shardVersion: [ Timestamp 6000|121, ObjectId('584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e') ], epoch
: ObjectId('584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e') }
```

**Excerpt from mongo log when 5bn+ elements are ingested - notice that the inserts are taking over 10 minutes now for 1000 documents!:**

```
2016-12-14T10:15:09.266+0000 W SHARDING [conn7948] Finding the split vector for db.d1 over { _id: "hashed" } keyCount: 59074 numSplits: 3295 look
edAt: 49399 took 147703ms
2016-12-14T10:15:09.270+0000 I COMMAND  [conn7948] command admin.$cmd command: splitVector { splitVector: "db.d1", keyPattern: { _id: "hashed" },
 min: { _id: 8286917826972549101 }, max: { _id: 8891696537615988474 }, maxChunkSizeBytes: 67108864, maxSplitPoints: 0, maxChunkObjects: 250000 } 
keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1521105 reslen:78136 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 3042212 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 152
1106 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1521106 }, acquireWaitCount: { r: 4 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 273 } } } protocol:op_command 147707m
s
2016-12-14T10:15:09.272+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.132.0.27:57186 #7950 (98 connections now open)
2016-12-14T10:15:09.275+0000 I SHARDING [conn7950] warning: log line attempted (96kB) over max size (10kB), printing beginning and end ... receiv
ed splitChunk request: { splitChunk: "db.d1", keyPattern: { _id: "hashed" }, min: { _id: 8286917826972549101 }, max: { _id: 8891696537615988474 }
, from: "shardrepl6", splitKeys: [ { _id: 8287101346889983059 }, { _id: 8287284735574907001 }, { _id: 8287468462323984570 }, { _id: 8287652170283
995411 }, { _id: 8287835497934387608 }, { _id: 8288018804450410355 }, { _id: 8288203522286937586 }, { _id: 8288388071505970055 }, { _id: 82885716
40651055014 }, { _id: 8288755180953265490 }, { _id: 8288938525600999756 }, { _id: 8289121602315847626 }, { _id: 8289303486256147041 }, { _id: 828
9487583455291418 }, { _id: 8289670676306614691 }, { _id: 8289854621499682550 }, { _id: 8290039202265877300 }, { _id: 8290222816842142600 }, { _id
: 8290407380208535449 }, { _id: 8290591646991349090 }, { _id: 8290775216085028368 }, { _id: 8290958397483060614 }, { _id: 8291141296044448774 }, 
{ _id: 8291325782881743950 }, { _id: 8291509640956353313 }, { _id: 8291692615717188224 }, { _id: 8291875865635048179 }, { _id: 829205937649184666
7 }, { _id: 8292243673713657589 }, { _id: 8292427637936143831 }, { _id: 8292611257535749373 }, { _id: 8292795483981231158 }, { _id: 8292978669576
490373 }, { _id: 8293161968622707955 }, { _id: 8293345020701432227 }, { _id: 8293527882782566480 }, { _id: 8293711119262214324 }, { _id: 82938944
23409576856 }, { _id: 8294078020795137503 }, { _id: 8294261767542526273 }, { _id: 8294443892466553095 }, { _id: 8294627093936215270 }, { _id: 829
4809793561574760 }, { _id: 8294993822250254718 }, { _id: 8295177652382819277 }, { _id: 8295360493433435532 }, { _id: 8295545257671541454 }, { _id
: 8295728932259232603 }, { _id: 8295913123304033493 }, { _id: 8296096457342755886 }, { _id: 8296280022998881301 }, { _id: 8296464671386836894 }, 
{ _id: 8296647186544445907 }, { _id: 8296830323943653126 }, { _id: 8297013730098864353 }, { _id: 8297196185619634257 }, { _id: 829737940146222018
0 }, { _id: 8297564988642525703 }, { _id: 8297747491525850110 }, { _id: 8297931581379542681 }, { _id: 8298114993102153399 }, { _id: 8298297439986
149518 }, { _id: 8298480444951235977 }, { _id: 8298663990688993348 }, { _id: 8298847055994867152 }, { _id: 8299031052877402611 }, { _id: 82992151
24614070361 }, { _id: 8299398215999968277 }, { _id: 8299582388940175975 }, { _id: 8299765821373923699 }, { _id: 8299950810133585214 }, { _id: 830
0133645889704871 }, { _id: 8300315774024380628 }, { _id: 8300499423759882486 }, { _id: 8300682010031403080 }, { _id: 8300865738536319852 }, { _id
: 8301049781229486084 }, { _id: 8301232456988002710 }, { _id: 8301415794714171555 }, { _id: 8301599451945947359 }, { _id: 8301783564425118532 }, 
{ _id: 8301968056396672988 }, { _id: 8302151637208684223 }, { _id: 8302333658023334194 }, { _id: 8302517935322753985 }, { _id: 830270052609467309
8 }, { _id: 8302883964901452771 }, { _id: 8303066862469161182 }, { _id: 8303249789429502361 }, { _id: 8303433114392011605 }, { _id: 8303616070263
699043 }, { _id: 8303799771311359310 }, { _id: 8303983170608151334 }, { _id: 8304166553694211715 }, { _id: 8304349400014341014 },
...
d: 8890990516605405909 }, { _id: 8891174917314061663 }, { _id: 8891360375988727310 }, { _id: 8891543753314122854 } ], configdb: "configrep/nohdp-m:27019,nohdp-w-0:27019,nohdp-w-1:27019", shardVersion: [ Timestamp 6000|49, ObjectId('584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e') ], epoch: ObjectId('584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e') }

2016-12-14T10:15:09.278+0000 I SHARDING [conn7950] distributed lock 'db.d1' acquired for 'splitting chunk [{ _id: 8286917826972549101 }, { _id: 8891696537615988474 }) in db.d1', ts : 58511bad1fce2179d2bc31de
2016-12-14T10:15:09.279+0000 I SHARDING [conn7950] remotely refreshing metadata for db.d1 based on current shard version 6|96080||584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e, current metadata version is 6|96089||584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e
2016-12-14T10:15:09.290+0000 I SHARDING [conn7950] metadata of collection db.d1 already up to date (shard version : 6|96080||584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e, took 11 ms)
2016-12-14T10:15:09.294+0000 W SHARDING [conn7950] splitChunk cannot find chunk [{ _id: 8286917826972549101 },{ _id: 8891696537615988474 }) to split, the chunk boundaries may be stale
2016-12-14T10:15:09.297+0000 I SHARDING [conn7950] distributed lock with ts: 58511bad1fce2179d2bc31de' unlocked.
2016-12-14T10:15:09.298+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7950] end connection 10.132.0.27:57186 (97 connections now open)
2016-12-14T10:16:04.652+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7947] end connection 10.132.0.27:57152 (96 connections now open)
2016-12-14T10:19:31.075+0000 I COMMAND  [conn98] command db.d1 command: insert { insert: "d1", documents: 186, ordered: false, shardVersion: [ Timestamp 6000|49, ObjectId('584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e') ] } ninserted:186 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:217 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 189, w: 189 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 189 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { w: 186 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { w: 186 } } } protocol:op_command 136ms
2016-12-14T10:20:09.270+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7948] end connection 10.132.0.27:57158 (95 connections now open)
2016-12-14T10:26:19.571+0000 I COMMAND  [conn91] command db.d1 command: insert { insert: "d1", documents: 170, ordered: false, shardVersion: [ Timestamp 6000|49, ObjectId('584ee95d47c9d485eeba7e9e') ] } ninserted:170 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:217 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 173, w: 173 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 173 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { w: 170 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { w: 170 } } } protocol:op_command 122ms
```

**MongoDB Configuration:**

```
| Name       | Role 1        | Role 2  |
|------------|---------------|---------|
| nohdp-m    | Config Server |         |
| nohdp-w-0  | Config Server |         |
| nohdp-w-1  | Config Server |         |
| nohdp-w-2  | Shard 1       | Router1 |
| nohdp-w-3  | Shard 2       | Router2 |
| nohdp-w-4  | Shard 3       | Router3 |
| nohdp-w-5  | Shard 4       | Router4 |
| nohdp-w-6  | Shard 5       | Router5 |
| nohdp-w-7  | Shard 6       | Router6 |
| nohdp-w-8  | Replica 1     |         |
| nohdp-w-9  | Replica 2     |         |
| nohdp-w-10 | Replica 3     |         |
| nohdp-w-11 | Replica 4     |         |
| nohdp-w-12 | Replica 5     |         |
| nohdp-w-13 | Replica 6     |         |
```

**Excerpt from the stats() command at the end of an ingestion run:**

```
mongos> db.d1.stats()
{
    "sharded" : true,
    "capped" : false,
    "ns" : "db.d1",
    "count" : 5939228000,
    "size" : NumberLong("3377887008160"),
    "storageSize" : NumberLong("1496882728960"),
    "totalIndexSize" : 223020806144,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 60463452160,
        "_id_hashed" : 162557353984
    },
    "avgObjSize" : 568.7417637713185,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "nchunks" : 66586,
    "shards" : {
        "shardrepl1" : {
            "ns" : "db.d1",
            "count" : 989892578,
            "size" : 562994179550,
            "avgObjSize" : 568,
            "storageSize" : 249483833344,
            "capped" : false,
            "wiredTiger" : {
                "metadata" : {
                    "formatVersion" : 1
                },
                "creationString" : "allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=snappy,cache_resident=false,checksum=on,colgroups=,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,encryption=(keyid=,name=),exclusive=false,extractor=,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,ignore_in_memory_cache_size=false,immutable=false,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=true,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=64MB,log=(enabled=true),lsm=(auto_throttle=true,bloom=true,bloom_bit_count=16,bloom_config=,bloom_hash_count=8,bloom_oldest=false,chunk_count_limit=0,chunk_max=5GB,chunk_size=10MB,merge_max=15,merge_min=0),memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=false,prefix_compression_min=4,source=,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,type=file,value_format=u",
                "type" : "file",
                "uri" : "statistics:table:collection-11-4419223010582756584",
                "LSM" : {
                    "bloom filter false positives" : 0,
                    "bloom filter hits" : 0,
                    "bloom filter misses" : 0,
                    "bloom filter pages evicted from cache" : 0,
                    "bloom filter pages read into cache" : 0,
                    "bloom filters in the LSM tree" : 0,
                    "chunks in the LSM tree" : 0,
                    "highest merge generation in the LSM tree" : 0,
                    "queries that could have benefited from a Bloom filter that did not exist" : 0,
                    "sleep for LSM checkpoint throttle" : 0,
                    "sleep for LSM merge throttle" : 0,
                    "total size of bloom filters" : 0
                },
                "block-manager" : {
                    "allocations requiring file extension" : 0,
                    "blocks allocated" : 0,
                    "blocks freed" : 0,
                    "checkpoint size" : 249483755520,
                    "file allocation unit size" : 4096,
                    "file bytes available for reuse" : 61440,
                    "file magic number" : 120897,
                    "file major version number" : 1,
                    "file size in bytes" : 249483833344,
                    "minor version number" : 0
                },
                "btree" : {
                    "btree checkpoint generation" : 7,
                    "column-store fixed-size leaf pages" : 0,
                    "column-store internal pages" : 0,
                    "column-store variable-size RLE encoded values" : 0,
                    "column-store variable-size deleted values" : 0,
                    "column-store variable-size leaf pages" : 0,
                    "fixed-record size" : 0,
                    "maximum internal page key size" : 368,
                    "maximum internal page size" : 4096,
                    "maximum leaf page key size" : 2867,
                    "maximum leaf page size" : 32768,
                    "maximum leaf page value size" : 67108864,
                    "maximum tree depth" : 0,
                    "number of key/value pairs" : 0,
                    "overflow pages" : 0,
                    "pages rewritten by compaction" : 0,
                    "row-store internal pages" : 0,
                    "row-store leaf pages" : 0
                },
                "cache" : {
                    "bytes currently in the cache" : 33151,
                    "bytes read into cache" : 15496,
                    "bytes written from cache" : 0,
                    "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 0,
                    "data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 0,
                    "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 0,
                    "in-memory page passed criteria to be split" : 0,
                    "in-memory page splits" : 0,
                    "internal pages evicted" : 0,
                    "internal pages split during eviction" : 0,
                    "leaf pages split during eviction" : 0,
                    "modified pages evicted" : 0,
                    "overflow pages read into cache" : 0,
                    "overflow values cached in memory" : 0,
                    "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
                    "page written requiring lookaside records" : 0,
                    "pages read into cache" : 5,
                    "pages read into cache requiring lookaside entries" : 0,
                    "pages requested from the cache" : 4,
                    "pages written from cache" : 0,
                    "pages written requiring in-memory restoration" : 0,
                    "unmodified pages evicted" : 0
                },
                "cache_walk" : {
                    "Average difference between current eviction generation when the page was last considered" : 0,
                    "Average on-disk page image size seen" : 0,
                    "Clean pages currently in cache" : 0,
                    "Current eviction generation" : 0,
                    "Dirty pages currently in cache" : 0,
                    "Entries in the root page" : 0,
                    "Internal pages currently in cache" : 0,
                    "Leaf pages currently in cache" : 0,
                    "Maximum difference between current eviction generation when the page was last considered" : 0,
                    "Maximum page size seen" : 0,
                    "Minimum on-disk page image size seen" : 0,
                    "On-disk page image sizes smaller than a single allocation unit" : 0,
                    "Pages created in memory and never written" : 0,
                    "Pages currently queued for eviction" : 0,
                    "Pages that could not be queued for eviction" : 0,
                    "Refs skipped during cache traversal" : 0,
                    "Size of the root page" : 0,
                    "Total number of pages currently in cache" : 0
                },
                "compression" : {
                    "compressed pages read" : 1,
                    "compressed pages written" : 0,
                    "page written failed to compress" : 0,
                    "page written was too small to compress" : 0,
                    "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : 0,
                    "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : 0,
                    "raw compression call succeeded" : 0
                },
                "cursor" : {
                    "bulk-loaded cursor-insert calls" : 0,
                    "create calls" : 1,
                    "cursor-insert key and value bytes inserted" : 0,
                    "cursor-remove key bytes removed" : 0,
                    "cursor-update value bytes updated" : 0,
                    "insert calls" : 0,
                    "next calls" : 0,
                    "prev calls" : 1,
                    "remove calls" : 0,
                    "reset calls" : 1,
                    "restarted searches" : 0,
                    "search calls" : 0,
                    "search near calls" : 0,
                    "truncate calls" : 0,
                    "update calls" : 0
                },
                "reconciliation" : {
                    "dictionary matches" : 0,
                    "fast-path pages deleted" : 0,
                    "internal page key bytes discarded using suffix compression" : 0,
                    "internal page multi-block writes" : 0,
                    "internal-page overflow keys" : 0,
                    "leaf page key bytes discarded using prefix compression" : 0,
                    "leaf page multi-block writes" : 0,
                    "leaf-page overflow keys" : 0,
                    "maximum blocks required for a page" : 0,
                    "overflow values written" : 0,
                    "page checksum matches" : 0,
                    "page reconciliation calls" : 0,
                    "page reconciliation calls for eviction" : 0,
                    "pages deleted" : 0
                },
                "session" : {
                    "object compaction" : 0,
                    "open cursor count" : 1
                },
                "transaction" : {
                    "update conflicts" : 0
                }
            },
            "nindexes" : 2,
            "totalIndexSize" : 35938430976,
            "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 10082500608,
                "_id_hashed" : 25855930368
            },
            "ok" : 1
        },
```

Comment: MongoDB uses mmap for every document it stores (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#mmapv1-storage-engine). When a mongod instance exhaust its memory, the database performance drops drastically as page faults occur. I believe WiredTiger also uses mmap under the hood.

Comment: Thanks strucotte06 - we did look into this but our results found that the performance remains good for a long time after peak memory usage is met. This would seem to imply that it isn't simply an issue of flushing and reading from disk I think.

Comment: The only strange behaviour seems to be centred on the splitChunk/Vector calls which appear to block inserts when they become large enough (which is the case once a few billion elements are ingested). Does anyone know why this might be the case or what splitChunk/Vector actually does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is encountering the same issue, we managed to resolve this by doing the following:

1. Tweaking the chunk size within a shard (not to be confused with batch size)
2. Increasing the initial number of chunks upon the creation of a collection

Example settings we used to diagnose if this was part of the issue:
Chunk Size: 1024 mb (Maximum)
Initial Chunks: 49152 (That is 8192 per shard which is the maximum limit)

Doing so meant that mongodb no longer had to split chunks continuously (which was blocking the ingestion calls).